# How to redraw an active x control in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++

How to redraw an active x control in visual C++ programmatically??

Answer (score 1):

You just redraw the parent which is hosting the ActiveX control. Call the Invalidate for the Rect object of the ActiveX.